# Action semantics and Operational semantics in UML

Tags: uml

1. What are the differences between `action semantics` and `operational semantics` of a UML model?
2. Is there a standard specification for each one of them? Is there implementation tool support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What are the differences between action semantics and operational semantics of a UML model?

They are related but separate initiatives.  The action semantics is the earlier initiative.  It grew out of an acknowledgement that UML could not be used to build executable models because it lacked constructs for describing processing operations: assignment, event generation, etc.  The original intent was to produce an action *language* to address these deficiencies.  However: those involved could not agree on the language syntax.  So instead they produced the action *semantics*: a definition of the constructs required at the abstract syntax level only.  Vendors/implementers were then free to use their own surface syntax.

There have been various initiatives to produce an operational semantics for UML ([some examples](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=uml%20operational%20semantics)).  However, by and large, they were not produced by or for the OMG directly.  Most were independent research initiatives.

To my knowledge, there is no single, normative Operational Semantics for UML.  The closest things are probably [fUML](http://www.omg.org/spec/FUML/) and related [Alf](http://www.omg.org/spec/ALF/) specifications.  fUML formalises a subset of UML for the express purpose of building executable models.  Alf is a concrete syntax for fUML.
 fUML defines an *Execution* Semantics which it describes as "the behavioral semantics of UML constructs that specify operational action over time, describing or constraining allowable behavior in the domain being modeled".

Alf/fUML can be seen as an evolution of the original action semantics work.  Although the title of the Alf Spec is `Concrete Syntax for a UML Action Language` it includes syntax for all the elements required to build executable models including classes, relationships, state models, etc.

> Is there a standard specification for each one of them?

- The action semantics was originally released as a separate specification which was then merged into the main UML specification at version 1.5 - specs [here](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/).
- [Alf](http://www.omg.org/spec/ALF/) and [fUML](http://www.omg.org/spec/FUML/) (as linked above)

> Is there implementation tool support?

There is a reference implementation for Alf & fUML [here](http://modeldriven.org/alf/).  Various tools support building executable models using action languages, e.g. the [xtuml editor](http://xtuml.org/) (free, open source) and [MagicDraw](http://www.nomagic.com/) via the [Cameo simulation toolkit](http://www.nomagic.com/products/magicdraw-addons/cameo-simulation-toolkit.html) (proprietary).

hth.

PS: You might want to think about accepting answers to other questions you've asked...

Comment: First of all ,I am very glad because you are answer my question
Secondly ,I mostly accept the best answer which is supported by real life examples ,useful links or any other types of evidence
when I am not sure whether the answer is best or not because of lacking in evidences I vote it up because it adds something useful to me and wait a votes, comments  from other members to allow them  share and add more meaning to the answer.

Comment: I would like to Thank you for letting me take a look at the earlier versions of UML specification, it is very helpful
moreover, I am a fan of your answers and I think I voted up most of your UML answers

Comment: #Could you please clarify the following part of your answer a bit?
`However: those involved could not agree on the language syntax. So instead they produced the action semantics: a definition of the constructs required at the abstract syntax level only. Vendors/implementers were then free to use their own surface syntax.`

Comment: #I have noticed that `Papyrus` support for Alf please take a look at the following:
http://www.omg.org/news/meetings/tc/agendas/va/xUML_pdf/Cucurru.pdf

Hope to you the best and Thank you for your consideration

Comment: re. Action Language Syntax: the committee had people with diverse opinions.  Some wanted a syntax that looked familiar to 3GL programmers - so 'C like'.  Some argued it should deliberately *not* be 'C like' because it was not meant to be a 'programming language'.  A compromise couldn't be found apparently.  So they standardised the abstract syntax, not a concrete one.

Comment: re. Papyrus: I don't know the tool so inf limited to what google can find.  The forum post here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366510/ suggests the alf editor hasn't yet been fully integrated into papyrus.  You might want to post a question to the forum to find out latest.